# Components dynamically created inside state don't update when store changes

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-props, viro-media

I'm sure the `store` updates (I'm using redux), 'cause I can get the updated value in `componentWillReceiveProps`, but in my dynamically created components the `props` won't update (mainting the value of props when the component was being created).

How I create the components:

```
_getFetchDataDevice(...) {
    [...]
    coordinatesObjectsAR.forEach((tempObject, i) => {
        objectsComponenets.push(
          <ViroFlexView width={10} key={"viro_flex_"+i} transformBehaviors={["billboard"]} scale={[0.7*(distanceFromObjectsAR[i]/60),0.68*(distanceFromObjectsAR[i]/60),0.9*(distanceFromObjectsAR[i]/60)]}  position={[coordinatesObjectsAR[i].x,0,coordinatesObjectsAR[i].z]} height={16} backgroundColor={'pink'} style={{ flexDirection: 'column' }} >
          <ViroFlexView key={"viro_flex_inside_"+i} backgroundColor={'white'} style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column' }} >
              <ViroText
              key={"distance_"+i}
              backgroundColor={'pink'}
              style={{ flex: 1, color: 'purple', marginLeft:.2 }}
              text={ this.props.distanceBetweenUserLocationAndPoints[i].toFixed(2).toString() + "m\n"}
              fontSize={162} />

              <ViroText
              key={"xy_"+i}
              backgroundColor={'pink'}
              style={{ flex: 1, color: 'purple', marginLeft:.2 }}
              text={"x:"+coordinatesObjectsAR[i].x.toFixed(2).toString()+",y:"+coordinatesObjectsAR[i].z.toFixed(2).toString()}
              fontSize={162} />

              <ViroText
              key={"title_"+i}
              backgroundColor={'pink'}
              style={{ flex: 1, color: 'purple', marginLeft:.2 }}
              text={jsonObjects[i].title}
              fontSize={162} />

              <ViroImage onClick={() => {this._startNavigationToLocal(i)}}
                  height={8}
                  width={6.75}
                  key={"button_"+i}
                  source={require("../resource/image/navigation.png")}
              />

          </ViroFlexView>

        </ViroFlexView>
        );
      });

   this.setState({objects: objectsComponenets});
   [...]
}
```

The props I need to get the updated value is **this.props.distanceBetweenUserLocationAndPoints**.

The render of the dynamically created components stored inside the state `objects` is:

```
return (
          <ViroARScene onTrackingUpdated={this._onTrackingUpdated} onAnchorFound={this._foundAnchor}>

              <ViroText text={"Compass: "+compassDegree} transformBehaviors={["billboard"]} scale={[.5, .5, .5]} position={[0,0,-1]} style={styles.helloWorldTextStyle} />
              {this.state.objects}
              <ViroBox position={[0,0,-1]} scale={[.3, .3, .1]}/>
               <ViroAmbientLight color={"#aaaaaa"} influenceBitMask={1} />

          </ViroARScene>
        );
```

The _getFetchDataDevice(...) is called inside a lifecycle method.

The `this.state.objects` works and renders the corrects Views I intended to, but when the **this.props.distanceBetweenUserLocationAndPoints** updates, the reference of it inside the dynamically created components don't update. Already tried to pass the props to local state, didn't work either.

Comment: References to state or props won't update for dynamically created components that are stored in state - they will only have the values of state/props at the time you created the components originally. What's the motivation to store `objectComponents` in `state` instead of just rendering and returning `objectComponents` from `_getFetchDataDevice` on reach render?

Comment: I thought that because it is a state it would be updatable. Anyway, I changed the code to make ```_getFetchDataDevice (...)``` return  ```objectsComponenets``` and call it ```{this._getFetchDataDevice()}``` in render, but now I have views being created multiple times, that also is why I was storing ```objectsComponenets``` in a state, cause ```_getFetchDataDevice``` must be called only once inside the lifecycle method that ensures that.

Comment: Perhaps there's a way to split out the data portion of `getFetchDataDevice` that can only happen once to set some state, and then a separate `render` helper that combines the `state` from `getFetchDataDevice` with any updated `props` to render your components correctly?